# calculate the difference of days between two dates in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I need to in my application to be able to calculate the difference of days between two dates. I tried a few ways that would give us the difference between the days of the future, but I need to get the past right as well.

I try with `val currentTime = Calendar.getInstance().time`

Answer (score 3):

Oh boy, you haven't realized it yet, but you just opened pandoras box: Time is very weird (especially in the past) and it is not as simple as calculating the difference between two timestamps. If you want to understand the insanity, I highly recommend [this video by Tom Scott](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5wpm-gesOY).

But anyway, to your question:

```
import java.time.Duration
import java.time.LocalDate

val firstTimestampInclusive = LocalDate.of(2000, 2, 27)
val secondTimestampExclusive = LocalDate.of(2000, 3, 1)
val numberOfDays = Duration.between(firstTimestampInclusive.atStartOfDay(), secondTimestampExclusive.atStartOfDay()).toDays()
println("Number of days between $firstTimestampInclusive and $secondTimestampExclusive: $numberOfDays")
```

This will print the following:

```
Number of days between 2000-02-28 and 2000-03-01: 2
```

Edit: For many reasons, using `java.util.Date` and `java.util.Calendar` is discouranged and you should use `java.time` instead (as I usggested in my answer).

Comment: thanks for your concern I fix it by a trick

Comment: It might depends on Android API version you support. In my case my bottom line is ```API 21``` when the most of ```java.time``` features require ```API 26```

Answer (score -1):

```
val cal = Calendar.getInstance()
cal.time = date1
val day1 = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR)

val cal2 = Calendar.getInstance()
cal2.time = date2
val day2 = cal2.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR)
```

day1 and day2 are integers between 0-365

Comment: You should not use `Calendar` and `java.util.Date` anymore. Use classes from `java.time` instead.

Comment: There are cases where this will give you the wrong result, and it is also not usable if the two dates are not in the same year. https://gist.github.com/timvisee/fcda9bbdff88d45cc9061606b4b923ca